# Best ffmpeg compression settings for fast seeking of long 4 hour clip

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I've got a low-resolution 4 hour clip, and need to do a lot of seeking in the video to write down when stuff happens.

Do you have any suggestions for what format/settings would be the most "seek-friendly?"  Right now it is a H264 mp4, ~200mb on disk, and every time I move the playback bar to a new part, it stops and thinks for a few seconds - especially if I have to back up 20 seconds.  I'm looking to be able to move backwards and forwards as fast as possible.  Maybe throwing in more keyframes?  A different video format that is less compressed, but more skip-around optimized?